# Does html/css have layers and how to use with opacity?

Tags: html, css

I've designed a site [here](http://4309.co.uk) and introduced some letters like so:

```
<div class="d">d</div>
<div class="e">e</div>
<div class="s">s</div>
<div class="i">i</div>
<div class="g">g</div>
<div class="n">n</div>
```

The red letters I've given opacity to like so:

```
.e {font-size: 500px; position: relative; bottom: 650px; left: 
100px; color: red; opacity: 0.2}
```

Now `d` and `e` work well together. The opaque `e` overlaps the solid `d` as it should. However, when I want the opaque `e`to overlap the solid `s` it doesn't, the `s`instead overlapping the `e`.

This seems to be an issue of layers or whatever word Lint or html uses?

So how to I move `s` to the back so `e` overlaps it?

Comment: Can you include all the CSS

Comment: `z-index` is your friend.

Comment: @BenM. Ah, thanks. How can I use it in this case please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `z-index` CSS property, here. A lower value, such as `z-index: 1` will stack the element below the element with a higher value, such as `z-index: 99`. The default value is `0`. So, assign your CSS classes different `z-index` values, accordingly. Remember, the `z` axis defines how your elements are stacked above or below each other.

If you want `e` to be stacked above `s`, `e` should have a higher `z-index` value.

Using example values, this will work:

`.e { z-index: 3; }
.s { z-index: 2; }`

Comment: I'll try. Thanks

Comment: Correct sir. Thanks